# Getting a task was canceled error when trying to seed roles in .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

In my .NET Core 3.0 application, I'm trying to seed new roles and users into the database the first time the application executes and connects to the database.

So I've written this simple class:

```
public static class UserAndRoleDataInitializer
{
    public static void SeedData(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> roleManager)
    {
        SeedRoles(roleManager);
        SeedUsers(userManager);
    }

    private static async void SeedRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> roleManager)
    {           
        var exists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("administrator");
        if (!exists)
        {               
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<Guid>("administrator"));
        }

        exists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("editor");
        if (!exists)
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<Guid>("editor"));
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

which is invoked from `Program.cs`:

```
var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<AppUser>>();
var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>>>();
UserAndRoleDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager);
```

Each time `SeedData` is executed I get the following error:

> **System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException**: 'A task was canceled.'

on the first line of `SeedRoles`: **`var exists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("administrator");`**

I've researched the web trying to find some answers but couldn't find anything similar to my use case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you try doing this in `Startup.cs`?

Comment: @bolkay I've already tried this, but I still get the same error.

Comment: The Visual Studio tags should only be used when the question is *about* Visual Studio.

Comment: Your method `SeedRoles` is async and returns void. Try returning a Task instead; and then await it: `await SeedRoles(roleManager);`

Comment: You should also change the ` public static void SeedData` method to be `async Task`.

Comment: @Guilherme `public static void SeedData` is invoked from `public static void Main(string[] args)`. I cannot turn this into `async`, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments from @Guilherme were really very helpful.

This is what I did to get it work:

```
public static class UserAndRoleDataInitializer
{
    public static async Task<IdentityResult> SeedData(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> roleManager)
    {
        await SeedRoles(roleManager);
        await SeedUsers(userManager);

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }

    private static async Task<IdentityResult> SeedRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> roleManager)
    {                       
        var exists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Administrator");
        if (!exists)
        {               
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole<Guid>("Administrator"));
        }
        ...
        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }

    private static async Task<IdentityResult> SeedUsers(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
    {            
        var usr = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("admin");
        if (usr == null)
        {
            AppUser user = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = "admin",
                Email = "gbetsos@yahoo.com",
                FirstName = "Giorgos",
                LastName = "Betsos"
            };

            IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P@ssw0rd1!");

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Administrator");
            }
        }

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    } 
}
```

Last, but not least, this is how `SeedData` is invoked from `Main`:

```
 UserAndRoleDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager).Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

This function is async.

```
UserAndRoleDataInitializer.SeedData(userManager, roleManager).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

will do the trick.

Comment: `SeedData` is not async in the code I've listed on my question. Should I change it, if yes, then how?

Comment: according to 
private static **async** void SeedRoles(RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> roleManager)
it is async.

Comment: `SeedRoles` is different from `SeedData`, you mention the second method in your answer